# Mostrar resultado consulta mySQL con servidor express.js vía post

Tags: mysql, json, nodejs, express

quiero enviar vía post mediante un servidor express, un servicio HTTP Request, en nodejs el resultado de una consulta a una bbdd MySQL, el código es el siguiente:

```js
 var respuesta = bbdd.respuesta();
    res.send(
        [{
            "text": respuesta,
            "type": 'message'
        }]
    )
```

Sin embargo, la salida me sale como vacía, he probado la función Stringfy pero la salida me aparece como '{}'.

La función que hace la consulta a la bbdd es la siguiente:

```html
  function respuesta() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    function lee(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT texto FROM respuestas", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
        });
    };
    lee();
});

}
```

Gracias, por la ayuda.

Comment: Tu respuesta llega vacía porque la Promesa nunca resuelve. Si bien tienes el método de consulta a la BD envuelto en una Promesa, no llamas nunca a `resolve` o `reject`. Adicionalmente, para usar el valor de tu función como intentas hacerlo, deberías usar `await` dentro de una función `async`, o usar los métodos `then()` y `catch()` de las Promesas. Saludos

Comment: Puede que no me halla explicado demasiado bien, la función respuesta esta en otro script y la llamo desde este archivo. De hecho si ejecuto la función me devuelve:
RowDataPacket ('ejemplo de consulta'). Simplemente quiero que lea los datos para responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos los errores que tienes:

1. Nunca llamas a `resolve` o a `reject` dentro de tu Promesa.
2. Intentas usar el valor de tu Promesa inmediatamente sin usar `await`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea enviar el resultado de una consulta a una BD a la vista, usando Express y NodeJS.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Vas encaminado en la dirección correcta: *usar Promesas para envolver una consulta*, pero la ejecución falla.

Tienes una función llamada `respuesta`, y la misma devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Para que la Promesa devuelva un resultado (o un error) debes ejecutar los métodos `resolve` o `reject` de acuerdo al resultado de la consulta.

Podrías hacerlo así:

```js
function respuesta() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query("SELECT texto FROM respuestas", function (err, result, fields) {
      // si ocurre error en la consulta, rechazamos la Promesa
      if (err) {
        console.error(error.message); // <= mostramos el mensaje en consola
        return reject(error); // devolvemos una Promesa rechazada pasando como argumento el error recibido
      }
      // Si la consulta devuelve resultados, resuelvo la promesa con los mismos
      console.log(result);
      return resolve(result);
      // Si necesito los campos (fields) puedo devolver un objeto, dependerá de lo que necesites hacer
      // return resolve({result, fields});
    });
  });
}
```

Ahora, para usar este método tienes 2 opciones:

- Usar `then()` y `catch()` y escribir tu lógica usando este estilo.
- Usar tu mñetodo dentro de una función tipo `async` para esperar el resultado de la Promesa usando `await`:

**Usando `then()` y `catch`:**

```js
// En NodeJS, evita usar 'var', es preferible 'let' y 'const'
let respuesta = bbdd.respuesta();
respuesta
  .then(result => {
    // aqui manejas el resultado de la consulta
    return res.status(200).json({
      text: result,  // <= yo escogería otro nombre en vez de text.
      type: 'message'
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // aqui manejas si hubo error en la consulta
    return res.status(500).json({ error:<mensaje de error> }
  });
```

**Usando una función `async`:**

Suponiendo que este método lo llamas dentro de un *middleware* de Express, puedes declararlo como `async`:

```js
async (req, res, nex) => {
  //...

  // uso await para esperar el resultado de la promesa, y debo llamar a la misma
  // dentro de un bloque try catch
  try {
    let respuesta = await bbdd.respuesta();
    return res.status(200).json({ ... });
  } catch(e) {
    //manejo de error
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({ ... });
  }
}
```

Esa sería la lógica a implementar en este caso.